# Why do I get these errors: "deasync" & "node build.js", "fsevents" & "node install", "node-gyp", "make" errors on "yarn add"

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-gyp, fsevents, node-deasync

Please help me make sense of this big fat error output. At this point I don't know which end is up. I have been spinning my wheels for days on this.

This is **not** the first/only package installation that has given me these errors, but the project ran fine anyway, so I ignored it. Now I want a new package, and it won't install. I did not set up this project.

Using *React, Webpack, and Yarn* on *MacOS 10.14.6* with *Node* running through `nvm`. I have *Xcode command line tools* installed independently, and full *XCode* installed. I have not disturbed the `yarn.lock` file since receiving this project, but I believe I did update a few packages through yarn at some point.

```
myprojectweb $ yarn add redux-persist
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @date-io/moment@0.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "moment@^2.22.2".
warning " > @material-ui/icons@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "@material-ui/core@^3.0.0".
warning " > @material-ui/pickers@3.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "@date-io/core@^1.3.6".
warning " > connected-react-router@6.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-router@^4.3.1 || ^5.0.0".
warning " > mdi-material-ui@5.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@material-ui/core@^1.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning " > redux-persist@6.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "redux@>4.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠐ node-sass
[2/4] ⠐ deasync
[-/4] ⠐ waiting...
error /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/deasync: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/deasync
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/usr/bin/python"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/deasync/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/deasync',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:221:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: warning: 'ToBoolean' is deprecated: ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
X(Boolean)
^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:12: note: expanded from macro 'X'
      val->To ## TYPE(isolate->GetCurrentContext())                            \
           ^
<scratch space>:213:1: note: expanded from here
ToBoolean
^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2567:3: note: 'ToBoolean' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version.",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:221:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:40:1: warning: 'BooleanValue' is deprecated: BooleanValue can never throw. Use Isolate version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
X(bool, Boolean)
^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:15: note: expanded from macro 'X'
  return val->NAME ## Value(isolate->GetCurrentContext());                     \
              ^
<scratch space>:220:1: note: expanded from here
BooleanValue
^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2605:3: note: 'BooleanValue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("BooleanValue can never throw. Use Isolate version.",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:222:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:103:42: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'Local<v8::Context>'
  return scope.Escape(v8::Function::New( isolate
                                         ^~~~~~~
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:183:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Context> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:183:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context> &&' for 1st argument
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:187:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'v8::Isolate *'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:4171:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'context' here
      Local<Context> context, FunctionCallback callback,
                     ^
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:222:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5426:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
  ^
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:222:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:58: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:60: error: expected expression
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                           ^
```

**... MORE SIMILAR TRACE ERRORS, TOO MANY CHARACTERS FOR STACKOVERFLOW ...**

```
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:563:3: note: 'MarkIndependent' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/deasync.cc:3:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2690:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
9 warnings and 8 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5



warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@12.13.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:221:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: warning: 'ToBoolean' is deprecated: ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
X(Boolean)
^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:12: note: expanded from macro 'X'
      val->To ## TYPE(isolate->GetCurrentContext())                            \\\n           ^
<scratch space>:213:1: note: expanded from here
ToBoolean
^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2567:3: note: 'ToBoolean' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version.\",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:221:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:40:1: warning: 'BooleanValue' is deprecated: BooleanValue can never throw. Use Isolate version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
X(bool, Boolean)
^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:15: note: expanded from macro 'X'
  return val->NAME ## Value(isolate->GetCurrentContext());                     \\\n              ^
<scratch space>:220:1: note: expanded from here
BooleanValue
^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2605:3: note: 'BooleanValue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"BooleanValue can never throw. Use Isolate version.\",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:222:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:103:42: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'Local<v8::Context>'
  return scope.Escape(v8::Function::New( isolate
                                         ^~~~~~~
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:183:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Context> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:183:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context> &&' for 1st argument
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:187:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'v8::Isolate *'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:4171:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'context' here
      Local<Context> context, FunctionCallback callback,
                     ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:222:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5426:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
  ^
```

**... MORE SIMILAR TRACE ERRORS, TOO MANY CHARACTERS FOR STACKOVERFLOW ...**

```
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:82:
../src/constants.cc:107:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir));
          ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3402:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:82:
../src/constants.cc:108:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink));
          ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:3402:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/csf/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../fsevents.cc:85:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
               ^
../fsevents.cc:85:31: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                          ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:85:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:85:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                 ^
../fsevents.cc:85:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                         ^
                                                         ;
30 warnings and 14 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=5\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/Users/csf/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node /Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/csf/Documents/ORG/Local on disk/Projects - local/myproject/myprojectweb/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
myprojectweb $
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know *why* this worked, but running a regular yarn-upgrade cleared the errors. I still got warnings about dependencies.

I should have saved the terminal output from yarn-outdated before and after the upgrade, but alas, I did not.

I still show a few mismatched dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

deasync try´s to compile itself if it did not find a precompiled version for current Node version.

This compilation has additional requirements so it is easier to use deasync/Node combinations where precompiled packages exists:

- https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/106
- https://github.com/abbr/deasync-bin

Answer (score 1):

I've been on `node20` (unstable) and on node18.18.2, reverting back to `18.17.2` via `nvm install 18.17.1` and adding `"preinstall": "yarn global add node-gyp"` to `package.json` fixed it. It looks like there's a bug: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6842 (also a source of the answer).